# Using the Destructuring Alternative Operator ?// in jq

Tags: json, jq, destructuring

In the latest jq version 1.6 there is a feature [Destructuring Alternative Operator: ?//](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Advancedfeatures) I am trying to use this to parse my *clumsily converted XML*.

This is the simplified example I have been playing with on [jq play](https://jqplay.org/):

```
{"data":[
    {"fruit":"orange","details":  {"colour":"orange"}},
    {"fruit":"apple", "details": [{"colour":"red"},{"colour":"green"}]}
]}
```

The key point is sometimes `details` is an object and sometimes it's an array of objects, and to quote from the doc *"We can use the destructuring alternative operator to handle this structural change simply"*

If I change the input data so `details` is always an array I can easily create [the output I want](https://jqplay.org/s/SMLuwux5R8)

```
.data[] | "\(.fruit) - \(.details[].colour)"


{"data":[
    {"fruit":"orange","details": [{"colour":"orange"}]},
    {"fruit":"apple", "details": [{"colour":"red"},{"colour":"green"}]}
]}


"orange - orange"
"apple - red"
"apple - green"
```

However using the original data with ?// the best [I can come up with](https://jqplay.org/s/s7kAODIcj1) is:

```
.data[] as {$fruit, details: $colour} ?// {$fruit, details: $colour} | "\($fruit) - \($colour)"

"orange - {\"colour\":\"orange\"}"
"apple - [{\"colour\":\"red\"},{\"colour\":\"green\"}]"
```

[and this](https://jqplay.org/s/jOVViuXLZ2) (which is pretty much a copy of [one of the examples](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=.%5B%5D%20as%20%7B%24a%2C%20%24b%2C%20c%3A%20%7B%24d%7D%7D%20%3F%2F%2F%20%7B%24a%2C%20%24b%2C%20c%3A%20%5B%7B%24e%7D%5D%7D%20%7C%20%7B%24a%2C%20%24b%2C%20%24d%2C%20%24e%7D&j=%5B%7B%22a%22%3A%201%2C%20%22b%22%3A%202%2C%20%22c%22%3A%20%7B%22d%22%3A%203%2C%20%22e%22%3A%204%7D%7D%2C%20%7B%22a%22%3A%201%2C%20%22b%22%3A%202%2C%20%22c%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22d%22%3A%203%2C%20%22e%22%3A%204%7D%5D%7D%5D)):

```
.data[] as {$fruit, details: {$colour}} ?// {$fruit, details: [{$colour}]} | "\($fruit) - \($colour)"

"orange - orange"
"apple - red"
```

There are [solutions using if else](https://jqplay.org/s/ijrzPQXykC) but I am particularly interested in how this feature works and what I need to do to get it to create the output I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to generate the output you expect is by using `? //` rather than `?//`:

```
.data[]
| (.details | (.colour? // (.[] | .colour))) as $colour
| "\(.fruit) - \($colour)"
```

As for `?//`, you might be barking up the wrong tree: the destructuring-alternative operator is not stream-oriented. That is, when a non-empty array is matched with [$foo], $foo will only match the first item in the array, not the items in sequence.

However, if you really wanted to use `?//`, for your particular case you could write:

```
.data[]
| .details as [$colour1, $colour2] ?// $colour1
| "\(.fruit) - \($colour1|.colour)",
  "\(.fruit) - \($colour2//empty|.colour)"
```

Comment: The obvious follow up to *"the destructuring-alternative operator is not stream-oriented"* is why not? That would seem to make it much more powerful/useful and make this statement from the docs true *"We can use the destructuring alternative operator to handle this structural change simply"*. Maybe just the docs need updating to explain the limitations.

Comment: Presumably the functional enhancement you have in mind would look something like `[$first ... $rest]`? Anyway, by all means propose a documentation or functional enhancement at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues